# Add "new from date" filter in product grid in Magento Admin

Tags: php, magento

How can I add "new from date" filter in product grid in Magento Admin?
I'd like to modify the original grid and add this new filter. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try referring to this extension, you can add custom columns also (which includes "new from date").

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-product-grid.html

Note : After installation, if you get a 404 error, just log out of your admin panel and login again.